# Finding an open time slot in Google Calendar in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-calendar-api

i was wondering what a smart approach to finding an open time slot in Google calendar.
currently i'm using HTTP requests to Google Calendar API and specifically the freeBusy call.

i need to look for a 30 minute window specifically, so a brute force method i thought of was getting the current time, checking for a window, then iterating through the rest of the day by increasing the current time by 5 minutes. that seems very janky though.

here's the current code i have to check for to find a 30 minute spare block of time:

```
var date = {
    value: "2022-11-15",
  };
  var startTime = {
    value: "22:30",
  };
  var endTime = {
    value: "23:00",
  };

  var dateObj = {
    timeMin: date.value + "T" + startTime.value + ":00-08:00",
    timeMax: date.value + "T" + endTime.value + ":00-08:00",
    items: [
      {
        id: calendarId,
      },
    ],
    timeZone: "America/Vancouver",
  };
  console.log(dateObj);
  const test = {
    method: "POST",
    async: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(dateObj),
  };
  
  await fetch(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/freeBusy",

    test
  )
    .then((response) => response.json()) // Transform the data into json
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you only need one call to the `freeBusy` endpoint.

This will be my approach:

1. I make a call to `freeBusy` between the working hours.

```json
{
 "timeMax": "2022-11-17T08:00:00.000",
 "timeMin": "2022-11-17T17:00:00.000Z",
 "items": [{"id": "primary"}]
}
```

2. In the response I have the hours where the user isn't avalaible.

```json
...
 "calendars": {
  "primary": {
   "busy": [
    {
     "start": "2022-11-17T15:00:00Z",
     "end": "2022-11-17T15:30:00Z"
    },
    {
     "start": "2022-11-17T16:45:00Z",
     "end": "2022-11-17T17:15:00Z"
    }
   ]
  }
...
```

3. With that information and assuming that in my Frontend I have a form where the user can introduce a date and formatted as per [RFC3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339).

```js
const busyInfo = [
  {
    "start": "2022-11-17T15:00:00Z",
    "end": "2022-11-17T15:30:00Z"
  },
  {
    "start": "2022-11-17T16:45:00Z",
    "end": "2022-11-17T17:50:00Z"
  }
]
// 30 min in ms
const gap = 1.8e6
/*
/ Check if a user is busy 
/ @param {string} date in ms ex: "2022-11-17T17:11:00Z"
/ @param {boolean} if the customer is busy
/ @returns {boolean}
*/
function checkBusy(clientDate = "2022-11-17T16:46:00Z", isBusy = false) {
  clientDate = Date.parse(clientDate)
  for (const bi of busyInfo) {
    const [start, end] = [Date.parse(bi.start), Date.parse(bi.end)]
    if (start >= clientDate && clientDate + gap <= end) {
      isBusy = true
    }
  }
  return isBusy
}
```

The next steps are to control that action from your user in the Frontend.

Documentation:

- [`freeBusy` endpoint](https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/freebusy)
- [Time format RFC3339](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339)